# Firebase Cloud Functions Error: version `GLIBCXX_3.4.21' not found

Tags: firebase, google-cloud-functions

I recently just deployed a updated function with a very minor change (nothing that could ever cause a crash!). And all of a sudden, I see this crash error in the logs...

```
Error: /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libstdc++.so.6: version `GLIBCXX_3.4.21' not found (required by /user_code/node_modules/firebase-admin/node_modules/grpc/src/node/extension_binary/node-v48-linux-x64-glibc/grpc_node.node)
    at Error (native)
    at Object.Module._extensions..node (module.js:604:18)
    at Module.load (module.js:494:32)
    at tryModuleLoad (module.js:453:12)
    at Function.Module._load (module.js:445:3)
    at Module.require (module.js:504:17)
    at require (internal/module.js:20:19)
    at Object.<anonymous> (/user_code/node_modules/firebase-admin/node_modules/grpc/src/grpc_extension.js:32:13)
    at Module._compile (module.js:577:32)
    at Object.Module._extensions..js (module.js:586:10)
    at Module.load (module.js:494:32)
    at tryModuleLoad (module.js:453:12)
    at Function.Module._load (module.js:445:3)
    at Module.require (module.js:504:17)
    at require (internal/module.js:20:19)
    at Object.<anonymous> (/user_code/node_modules/firebase-admin/node_modules/grpc/src/client_interceptors.js:145:12)
```

> UPDATE: Firebase fixed this issue. Thanks for your support!

Comment: It could be a downage on Firebase's end... https://status.firebase.google.com

Comment: I'm having the same issue, keeping an eye on https://status.firebase.google.com/incident/Functions/18026 to be resolved and will try to deploy again. You're not alone!

Comment: Same problem, thanks Jamie, clearly it's not just me!

Comment: Same situation here. I'm new to Firebase and figured I did something horribly wrong.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you are still experiencing this issue you can delete and re-deploy the problematic function to the server.

Firebase has updated the status here with that workaround: https://status.firebase.google.com/incident/Functions/18026

It worked for me.

Answer (score 2):

Investigating an issue with Cloud Functions

Incident began at 2018-05-17 12:05 (all times are US/Pacific)

Check this https://status.firebase.google.com/